# keycloack client credentials --> 401

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, token, keycloak

I have a problem with keycloak and oauth2 identification.
I use client_credentials grant type to request an access_token :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://XXX/realms/YYY/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=CCC' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=6yqR3IEE...' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJS.....",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "refresh_expires_in": 0,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not-before-policy": 0,
    "scope": "profile good-service email groups"
}
```

Seems ok. and verification on jwt.io confirm.

```
{
  "exp": 1673290210,
  "iat": 1673289910,
  "jti": "b948569a-9597-4e1d-aab8-b95a24550965",
  "iss": "https://XXX/realms/YYY",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "f8b0676d-9b28-4eb6-82a2-12e21b77c8e3",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "CCC",
  "acr": "1",
  "allowed-origins": [
    "*"
  ],
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "default-roles-YYY",
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "profile good-service email groups",
  "email_verified": false,
  "clientId": "caravan",
  "clientHost": "XX.XX.XX.XX",
  "preferred_username": "service-account-caravan",
  "clientAddress": "XX.XX.XX.XX"
}
```

But when I try to verify access with this API :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://XXX/realms/YYY/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJS.....' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'token=eyJhbGciOiJS.....'
```

it return error 401

```
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Authentication failed."
}
```

how can my access token can not work ?? Am I misundestanding something ?

Answer (score 0):

You missed two items in body of `introspect` API.

You need to add the `client_id` and `client_secret`

Demo, using Keycloak v20.0.2 by curl from terminal.

And using `jq` for extract child field's value or pretty print.

#### #1 set configuration in environment variables.

```
CLIENT_ID=my-client
CLIENT_SECRET=d2IrqYfIcbjQuCqnzM8AoqFz0s9DBaJ0
REALM_NAME=my-realm
PORT=8180
```

#### #2 Get client token

```
CLIENT_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:'$PORT'/realms/'$REALM_NAME'/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=my-client' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret='$CLIENT_SECRET | jq -r '.access_token')
echo $CLIENT_TOKEN
```

Results

```
$ CLIENT_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:'$PORT'/realms/'$REALM_NAME'/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
> --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
> --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
> --data-urlencode 'scope=openid' \
> --data-urlencode 'client_id=my-client' \
> --data-urlencode 'client_secret='$CLIENT_SECRET | jq -r '.access_token')
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2588  100  2479  100   109   268k  12111 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  280k

$ echo $CLIENT_TOKEN
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ3YW9QMDlKcXZMX2hCX1pleEh5M2hPVXFNZ2UzVnlGc3g4Tm9Na2N4RVM0In0.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.CSOlC4wmGRs95q71Gr-IjavtjUaq8mykSjcg6sXOLn_VQH2i_rlYb7eBOthyHSloZrrHbzLVWgOZ2Ah2jJmgqJ5CKXcfi4gSSbyOMll5dI5AGK8QMhVoHWIs_CD8KCfXR5ca8kfeZLdbabqusLl_D6Cqcg2tavPb8SLDEfVLnbija1ZaeBjI0jSuEIkf0sxCaYl-vrnHkvgExN3i5AgZzJ4uoOAAWuBPHjVdDX5pa_s6adi_PGKM2YQlVvWbirwSznWmAFnVhBRFW8ZuKum9BmUTcknT1K65DVMAthNp5zuBzkuMaCmWFuIzwpYtRzfIy66THFKdppDnXEyoo99_Jg
```

#### #3 Introspect that token

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:'$PORT'/realms/'$REALM_NAME'/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id='$CLIENT_ID \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret='$CLIENT_SECRET  \
--data-urlencode 'token='$CLIENT_TOKEN | jq -r
```

Results

```
$ curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:'$PORT'/realms/'$REALM_NAME'/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect' \
> --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
> --data-urlencode 'client_id='$CLIENT_ID \
> --data-urlencode 'client_secret='$CLIENT_SECRET  \
> --data-urlencode 'token='$CLIENT_TOKEN | jq -r
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2094  100   715  100  1379   174k   336k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  511k
{
  "exp": 1673296269,
  "iat": 1673295969,
  "jti": "f634d751-7def-41f7-bdf4-29224c9621ad",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8180/realms/my-realm",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "249d4b48-70db-4360-80e2-739bef53bd6e",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "my-client",
  "preferred_username": "service-account-my-client",
  "email_verified": false,
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization",
      "default-roles-my-realm"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "my-client": {
      "roles": [
        "uma_protection"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "clientHost": "172.17.0.1",
  "clientId": "my-client",
  "clientAddress": "172.17.0.1",
  "client_id": "my-client",
  "username": "service-account-my-client",
  "active": true
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank, but i don’t inderstand : If I have to reauthent with client_id and password, what’s the interest of the token ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. There are no password. It only use client id /secret. Can you explain more detail what is you don't understand item?